# Correct mime type for .mp4

Tags: video, html5-video, mime-types

I have two applications as mentioned below:

1. Admin application  through which I am able to upload a .mp4 file to the server.
2. I am trying to download the .mp4 using mobile application in iPad.

---

- The Admin application is made by using asp.net 4.0 and SQL Server, IIS7.
- The Mobile application is made of asp.net mvc3, jquerymobile, HTML5.

As of now I have added mime type `video/mp4` for .mp4 in IIS7 mime types section.

When I am trying to download the .mp4 file in iPad I am seeing a dark black screen with cross arrow on it. Can anyone please help me to resolve the issue.

Please tell me whether the mime type `video/mp4` for .mp4 is correct.

Comment: application/octet-stream

Comment: @ZYiOS if you have an audio file in Internet Explore this doesn't work, instead should be use `audio/mp4`

Answer (score 331, accepted):

According to [RFC 4337](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4337.txt) § 2, `video/mp4` is indeed the correct Content-Type for MPEG-4 video.

Generally, you can find official MIME definitions by searching for the file extension and "IETF" or "RFC". The RFC (Request for Comments) articles published by the IETF (Internet Engineering Taskforce) define many Internet standards, including MIME types.

Answer (score 47):

`video/mp4`should be used when you have video content in your file. If there is none, but there is audio, you should use `audio/mp4`. If no audio and no video is used, for instance if the file contains only a subtitle track or a metadata track, the MIME should be `application/mp4`.
Also, as a server, you should try to include the `codecs` or `profiles` parameters as defined in [RFC6381](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6381), as this will help clients determine if they can play the file, prior to downloading it.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://help.encoding.com/knowledge-base/article/correct-mime-types-for-serving-video-files/, the correct mime type for `.mp4` is `video/mp4`

Comment: While this answer is correct (assuming that the .mp4 file contains video), the source given is not authoritative.

Answer (score 0):

When uploading .mp4 file into Perl script, using CGI.pm I see it as **video/mp** when printing out `Content-type` for the uploaded file.
I hope it will help someone.