# StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync() does not return mp4 files from a USB stick

Tags: c#, video, winrt-xaml

I'm writing an application that can upload image files and video files, and allow the user to upload from their 'Pictures' folder or a USB stick. Currently it can do everything except upload a video file from a USB stick. Images from the 'Pictures' folder are fine, images from a USB stick are fine, videos from the 'Pictures' folder are fine, but videos from a USB stick are not fine.

There really isn't much code to this:

```
private async Task SearchFoldersForMedia(StorageFolder folderToSearch)
{
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> allFilesInFolder = await folderToSearch.GetFilesAsync();

    // other code here...
}
```

It's pretty bare-bones, honestly. If my 'Pictures' folder has 3 videos (.mp4) then that one line will find three video files, but if my datastick has 3 videos then that same line will find nothing. If I look in either my datastick or my 'Pictures' folder for image files (.jpg, .jpeg, or .png) then they all get found as they should be.

What's causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in my Package.appxmanifest, not the code I had written. Solution found by following the advice used here:
[Correct mime type for .mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929940/correct-mime-type-for-mp4)

Incidentally, this means I was never really uploading the videos from my 'Pictures' folder, even though they seemed to get uploaded. I suspect the external drive wasn't even showing them as present was due to an increased protection level when dealing with external devices.