# Play large .mp4 video stored on Google Cloud Storage from on my website

Tags: javascript, video-streaming

I'm hoping someone can help me out with the issue I'm having, here is a summary:

I've uploaded some ~30minute long .mp4 videos on my Google Cloud Storage. I made the bucket/objects public, and am trying to play the file like so on my website:

```
<video
   ref={vid}
   autoPlay={true}
   controls={true}
>
   <source src={"https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucket/file.mp4"} type={"video/mp4"} />
</video>
```

The video element, only plays audio and does not play the video. It looks like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAkmx.png)

From what I understand, .mp4 stored anywhere on the cloud should behave like any regular .mp4 file. However this does not seem to be the case.

I'm looking for a free solution, but I have tried using Mux to stream the .mp4 file for me. This works. This leads me to believe I may need a service to stream the .mp4 files for me.

Can anyone help? I'd rather not use Mux. Is there anyway to directly stream the .mp4 from my google cloud without an extra service? Or is there another cloud storage service that I can use that may allow this? I have roughly ~50gb of personal videos.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is the HTTP header `content-type` set to for this object? Hint: it needs to be set correctly so that clients know the type of content. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929940/correct-mime-type-for-mp4

Comment: its set to video/mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the .mp4 files were that they were not optimized for the web. Link to the root cause explanation & solution can be found here : [HTML5 - How to stream large .mp4 files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328401/html5-how-to-stream-large-mp4-files)