Media Foundation Video Streaming
I'm able to stream MP3 audio with media foundation:
CComPtr<IMFAttributes> attrs;
bs; // an IMFByteStream implementation
...
attrs->SetGUID(MF_TRANSCODE_CONTAINERTYPE, MFTranscodeContainerType_MP3);
MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(0,&bs, attrs, &pSinkWriter);
...
pMediaTypeOutAudio->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFAudioFormat_MP3);
...
// Encoding
// pAudioSample contains PCM bytes 
pSinkWriter->WriteSample(OutAudioStreamIndex, pAudioSample);

And then my "bs" contains bytes which I can directly send to a http connection with Content-Type: audio/mpeg.
The question is how to do the same thing to stream video. Now I'm doing:
attrs->SetGUID(MF_TRANSCODE_CONTAINERTYPE, MFTranscodeContainerType_MPEG4);
...
pMediaTypeOutVideo->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264);
...
pSinkWriter->WriteSample(OutVideoStreamIndex, pVideoSample);
...

All these work, and I get an MP4 stream in my "bs", but when I send it to the browser with Content-Type: video/mp4, all I get is a loading forever screen, it seems that it wants to finish the mp4 video to play it.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying with Media Foundation?
I'm trying to look mpeg-dash but I'm not sure where to start, I found libdash but this seems to be only a playing library. I'm not sure If I can manage it with MF alone, I'm not also sure If i need to add a MPEG-4 description (see this).


I suggest you could refer to the Doc:Tutorial: Using the Sink Writer to Encode Video

@Jeaninez-MSFT this only says what I'm already doing, how to encode. The idea is to stream something that will be recognized by the browsers.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929940/correct-mime-type-for-mp4
video/mp4: A video file using the MPEG-4 file type. As far as I'm concerned, you need to set a MPEG-4 description. About mpeg-dash, it is related to HTTP.
